# PHP - Show searching Word with 5 surrounding Words

Tags: php, search, text, text-files, words

i am new here. i have a question about some PHP. I am working on a project at the moment. And now there is a Problem.

So, first of all: what is my "wish":
Have a text file, it contains content like this:

```
John Brown: Lives in New York, married, have 3 sons and love playing football
```

Now i need a PHP code, which read and search the text file, BUT show only special searching word with 5 words surround the searching word, so that the result should be like this:
I am search for **sons**, the result should be:
`John Brown: Have 3 sons and love playing`. **EDIT:** Forgot to say, that the name **John Brown** should stay with the search results.

Please help me.
Sorry for my bad englisch, living in germany :)

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
<?php
$search = 'sons';
$lines = file('file.txt'); 
// Store true when the text is found 
$found = false;
foreach($lines as $line) { 
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) { $found = true; echo $line; } 
} 
// If the text was not found, show a message 
if(!$found) { echo 'No match found'; }
?>
```

Comment: Your english is fine, but does it seem like we love sitting here giving out free code from start till end? :)

Comment: I have never said that! ;)

Comment: But you are expecting it, right? Please realize that you _have to_ make some effort on your own.

Comment: Of course, i have tried for myself.. but get not the result, that i should have. i tried like this:<?php
$search = 'sons';
$lines = file('file.txt');
// Store true when the text is found
$found = false;
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
  {
    $found = true;
    echo $line;
 
  }
}
// If the text was not found, show a message
if(!$found)
{
  echo 'No match found';
}

?>

Comment: See? We could have skipped all this if you had already posted the code. Anyways, tag added and code posted to the question. This way your question will be noticed better.

Comment: Oh! I am very sorry about that. :{

Answer (score 5):

Here, just for grins, is a solution that loops through the string counting spaces instead of exploding and imploding:

```
function context_find($haystack, $needle, $context) {
    $haystack=' '.$haystack.' ';
    if ($i=strpos($haystack, $needle)) {
        $start=$i;
        $end=$i;
        $spaces=0;

        while ($spaces < ((int) $context/2) && $start > 0) {
            $start--;
            if (substr($haystack, $start, 1) == ' ') {
                $spaces++;
            }
        }

        while ($spaces < ($context +1) && $end < strlen($haystack)) {
            $end++;
            if (substr($haystack,$end,1) == ' ') {
                $spaces++;
            }
        }

        while ($spaces < ($context +1) && $start > 0) {
            $start--;
            if (substr($haystack, $start, 1) == ' ') {
                $spaces++;
            }
        }

        return(trim(substr($haystack, $start, ($end - $start))));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
$h="Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimbel in the wabe";
$n="toves";
$c="5";

print context_find($h, $n, $c)."\n";
```

Returns:

```
the slithy toves did gyre
```

Also, it tries to return the right amount of context even when the search term is too close to the beginning, or the end:

```
$h="Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimbel in the wabe";
$n="brillig";
$c="5";

print context_find($h, $n, $c)."\n";
```

Returns:

```
Twas brillig and the slithy
```

Or even:

```
$h="Twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimbel in the wabe";
$n="wabe";
$c="5";
```

Which returns:

```
and gimbel in the wabe
```

This, of course, does nothing to loop through your input file, etc, for which other examples suffice.

Answer (score 4):

To me it sounds like a problem very well handled by regular expressions.

```
function find_words($haystack, $needle) {
    $regex = '%\w+\s\w+\s' . preg_quote($needle) . '\s\w+\s\w+%';

    if (preg_match($regex, $haystack, $matches)) {
        return $matches[0];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$s = 'John Brown: Lives in New York, married, have 3 sons and love playing football';
$search = 'sons';
var_dump(find_words($s, $search));
```

\w+ is one or more word chars, \s is a space and in the middle is the word you're searching for. Very easy to match more words or other chars or do a not exact word match, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

this code is just a example of how I would do it, and its not finished.

```
  function search($query,$str){
     $words = explode(' ',$str);
     $index = array_search($query, $words);
     return implode(' ', array_slice($words, $index-2, 6)); // sanitate "length of the array" vs $index
  }
  $file = file_get_contents('data');

  echo  search('sons',$file);
```

This function will return string with 2 words around the searched word.

Keep in mind, that $file could contain more than one searched words, and $index-2 can be smaller than length od the $words array.

If your data file contains 1 sentence on 1 line you could use it like this

```
  $file = file('data');
  foreach ($file as $line){
    echo search('sons',$line)."\n";
  }
```

Formore, if the name on each line is defined as "$Name: $sentence" use this function to find it

```
  function findName($str){
    $name = explode(':',  $str);
    return $name[0];
  }
```

Combined it looks like this:

```
  function search($query,$str){
     $words = explode(' ',$str);
     $index = array_search($query, $words);
     if ($idex === false){
       return false;
     }
     else{
     return implode(' ', array_slice($words, $index-2, 6)); // sanitate "length of the array" vs $index
     }
  }
  function findName($str){
    $name = explode(':',  $str);
    return $name[0];
  }

  $file = file('data');
  foreach ($file as $line){
    $string =  search('sons',$line);
    if ($string !== false){
      echo findName($line).': '.$string."\n";
    }
  }
```

You should be able to finish the code by yourself. If not, let me know.

Comment: Hmm, i dont know, but it doesnt work.. the result is this: **have 3**

Comment: sorry, I edited the code. See the change in array_slice function